# Remove first line that may include formatted text

Tags: vba, outlook

I edit my Outlook message before sending to remove the first line, which is used for an internal process, so I can send the email cleanly to the recipient.

The script works as long as the format is consistent within this first line. When the format varies, such as difference in color or italic or bold, the script fails to remove this line.

I'm trying to remove this line regardless of format while maintaining the formatting in the rest of the email body.

Example: BAAR-6546543456.
The code will fail with either BAAR-*6546543456.* or BAAR-**6546543456.** .

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim OutMail As Object
Dim PrintMail As Object
Dim FirstLetters As String
Dim LastPos As Long
Dim sHostName As String
Dim DirectoryLine As String

On Error GoTo EndTask

Set Item = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = Item.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

sHostName = Environ$("username")

FirstLetters = Left(OutMail.Body, 5)
LastPos = InStr(OutMail.Body, ".")

If Right(FirstLetters, 1) = "-" Then
    
    If RecordFlag = "R" Then
        Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With objMsg
                .Body = "Your document(s) have been dispatched on " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
                .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML ' send HTML
                .Display
            End With
        Set PrintMail = Item.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Else
        Dispatch_remark = " Dispatched to " & OutMail.To & "; " & OutMail.CC & " on " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
        OutMail.HTMLBody = OutMail.HTMLBody & Dispatch_remark
        Set PrintMail = Item.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End If

    Processing (this is the internal piece which is out of scope of this question)
    
    OutMail.HTMLBody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, DirectoryLine, "", , , 1)
    
    If RecordFlag = "R" Then
        objMsg.Delete
    Else
        OutMail.HTMLBody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, Trim(Dispatch_remark), "", 1)
    End If

End If

Set objMsg = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set PrintMail = Nothing
Set Item = Nothing

EndTask:

End Sub
```

My focus is on the Replace method portion of the script, which fails when the format is inconsistent:

```
    OutMail.HTMLBody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, DirectoryLine, "", , , 1)
    
    If RecordFlag = "R" Then
        objMsg.Delete
    Else
        OutMail.HTMLBody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, Trim(Dispatch_remark), "", 1)
    End If
```

Comment: Could you use `OutMail.Body` property instead of `OutMail.HTMLBody` in Replace, in order to exclude HTML formatting?

Answer (score 0):

This code inspects the active mail and has two ways to delete the line you want. The first is commented and you can use it if you are sure that the line you want to delete is this first one of the mail. If it isn't you should the loop part.
Choose the way you want and adapt to your code.

```
Sub Mail_DeleteParagraph()
    Dim Ins As Object: Set Ins = Application.ActiveInspector
    Dim Doc As Object: Set Doc = Ins.WordEditor
    Dim oPara As Object
    
    ' Delete first paragraph
    'Set oPara = Doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    'oPara.Delete
    
    ' Delete paragraph that starts with 'BAAR-' and has '.'
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each oPara In Doc.Paragraphs
        Debug.Print i & " - " & oPara.Range
        If Left(oPara.Range, 5) = "BAAR-" And InStr(1, oPara.Range, ".") > 0 Then
            oPara.Range.Delete
            exit sub
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next oPara
End Sub
```